# Using a PagedList with a ViewModel ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, pagedlist

I'm trying to using a PagedList in my ASP.Net application and I found this example on the Microsoft website http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

How is it possible to use a PagedList in a complex situation that uses a ViewModel? I'm trying to add a PagedList without success to the Instructor example posted here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

The problem is that the ViewModel is composed by classes and not simple fields, so I cannot convert the result with the ToPageList() method.

This is the ViewModel structure:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.ViewModels
{
    public class InstructorIndexData
    {
        public IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to join the three tables into the ViewModel and display the result in a View.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I modified the code as follow:

ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.ViewModels
{
    public class InstructorIndexData
    {
     public PagedList.IPagedList<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
     public PagedList.IPagedList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
     public PagedList.IPagedList<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? courseID,int? InstructorPage,int? CoursePage,int? EnrollmentPage)
{
 int instructPageNumber = (InstructorPage?? 1);
 int CoursePageNumber = (CoursePage?? 1);
 int EnrollmentPageNumber = (EnrollmentPage?? 1);
 var viewModel = new InstructorIndexData();
 viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors
    .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
    .Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))
    .OrderBy(i => i.LastName).ToPagedList(instructPageNumber,5);

 if (id != null)
 {
    ViewBag.InstructorID = id.Value;
    viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(
        i => i.ID == id.Value).Single().Courses.ToPagedList(CoursePageNumber,5);
 }

 if (courseID != null)
 {
    ViewBag.CourseID = courseID.Value;
    viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Courses.Where(
        x => x.CourseID == courseID).Single().Enrollments.ToPagedList(EnrollmentPageNumber,5);
 }

 return View(viewModel);
}
```

View

```
<div>
   Page @(Model.Instructors.PageCount < Model.Instructors.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Instructors.PageNumber) of @Model.Instructors.PageCount

   @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Instructors, page => Url.Action("Index", new {InstructorPage=page}))

</div>
```

I hope this would help you!!

Comment: What if Instructors has 100,000 records? They will all be loaded into memory just in case they are needed to load Courses? And how does PageCount get set? And the models are being used like some sort of in-memory db. There is no design.

Answer (score 30):

For anyone who is trying to do it without modifying your ViewModels AND not loading all your records from the database.

**Repository**

```
    public List<Order> GetOrderPage(int page, int itemsPerPage, out int totalCount)
    {
        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
        using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            orders = (from o in db.Orders
                      orderby o.Date descending //use orderby, otherwise Skip will throw an error
                      select o)
                      .Skip(itemsPerPage * page).Take(itemsPerPage)
                      .ToList();
            totalCount = db.Orders.Count();//return the number of pages
        }
        return orders;//the query is now already executed, it is a subset of all the orders.
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        int pagenumber = (page ?? 1) -1; //I know what you're thinking, don't put it on 0 :)
        OrderManagement orderMan = new OrderManagement(HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context);
        int totalCount = 0;
        List<Order> orders = orderMan.GetOrderPage(pagenumber, 5, out totalCount);
        List<OrderViewModel> orderViews = new List<OrderViewModel>();
        foreach(Order order in orders)//convert your models to some view models.
        {
            orderViews.Add(orderMan.GenerateOrderViewModel(order));
        }
        //create staticPageList, defining your viewModel, current page, page size and total number of pages.
        IPagedList<OrderViewModel> pageOrders = new StaticPagedList<OrderViewModel>(orderViews, pagenumber + 1, 5, totalCount);
        return View(pageOrders);
    }
```

**View**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList; 

@model IPagedList<Babywatcher.Core.Models.OrderViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    @if (Model.Count > 0)
    {


        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().orderId)
            </th>
            <!--rest of your stuff-->
        </table>

    }
    else
    {
        <p>No Orders yet.</p>
    }
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
</div>
```

## Bonus

Do above first, then perhaps use this!

Since this question is about (view) models, I'm going to give away a little solution for you that will not only be useful for paging, but for the rest of your application if you want to keep your entities separate, only used in the repository, and have the rest of the application deal with models (which can be used as view models).

**Repository**

In your order repository (in my case), add a static method to convert a model:

```
public static OrderModel ConvertToModel(Order entity)
{
    if (entity == null) return null;
    OrderModel model = new OrderModel
    {
        ContactId = entity.contactId,
        OrderId = entity.orderId,
    }
    return model;
}
```

Below your repository class, add this:

```
public static partial class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<OrderModel> SelectOrderModel(this IEnumerable<Order> source)
    {
        bool includeRelations = source.GetType() != typeof(DbQuery<Order>);
        return source.Select(x => new OrderModel
        {
            OrderId = x.orderId,
            //example use ConvertToModel of some other repository
            BillingAddress = includeRelations ? AddressRepository.ConvertToModel(x.BillingAddress) : null,
            //example use another extension of some other repository
            Shipments = includeRelations && x.Shipments != null ? x.Shipments.SelectShipmentModel() : null
        });
    }
}
```

And then in your `GetOrderPage` method:

```
    public IEnumerable<OrderModel> GetOrderPage(int page, int itemsPerPage, string searchString, string sortOrder, int? partnerId,
        out int totalCount)
    {
        IQueryable<Order> query = DbContext.Orders; //get queryable from db
        .....//do your filtering, sorting, paging (do not use .ToList() yet)

        return queryOrders.SelectOrderModel().AsEnumerable();
        //or, if you want to include relations
        return queryOrders.Include(x => x.BillingAddress).ToList().SelectOrderModel();
        //notice difference, first ToList(), then SelectOrderModel().
    }
```

Let me explain:

The static `ConvertToModel` method can be accessed by any other repository, as used above, I use `ConvertToModel` from some `AddressRepository`.

The extension class/method lets you convert an entity to a model. *This can be IQueryable or any other list, collection*.

Now here comes the magic: If you have executed the query BEFORE calling `SelectOrderModel()` extension, `includeRelations` inside the extension will be true because the `source` is NOT a database query type (not an linq-to-sql `IQueryable`). When this is true, the extension can call other methods/extensions throughout your application for converting models.

Now on the other side: You can first execute the extension and then continue doing LINQ filtering. **The filtering will happen in the database eventually**, because you did not do a `.ToList()` yet, the extension is just an layer of dealing with your queries. Linq-to-sql will eventually know what filtering to apply in the Database. The `inlcudeRelations` will be false so that it doesn't call other c# methods that SQL doesn't understand.

It looks complicated at first, extensions might be something new, but it's really useful. Eventually when you have set this up for all repositories, simply an `.Include()` extra will load the relations.

Comment: definitely the best solution I've found to date. All the others, including the Microsoft tutorials, don't use a layered architecture, as you would in a real commercial environment, and go direct to the repository from the controller and pass the PagedList back as the only object in the model..

Comment: Thanks, I'm using it for a while now with some additional sorting and filtering. Works great for simple applications when you just have to get the pages out there. #2017 confirmed ;)

Comment: Actually, `ToList()` executes your LINQ query, so your 1st snippet seems wrong. Instead, you should move the `.Skip(...).ToList()` in your `return` statement, so `totalCount` will return the number of pages BEFORE query execution, which is your purpose. This answer should be corrected.  
However, I +1'd because it helped me.

Comment: Hi Alex, the reason I have that is because most solutions require to load the entire set and then use pagination. This solution keeps what should be done in the repository, in the repository :). Sure selecting can be done later. In this example it doesn't do any filtering so it is not a problem to count everything. I, however, do have this differently but for the purpose of easy explanation I think I will leave it like it is now.

Comment: I know this post is old, while I do like this solution and it is very helpful especially the bonus info which is why I upped it a notch - too bad I could not notch it more; from my understanding Entity Framework is a repository pattern so having it in the controller - is somewhat like calling code to execute against the repository.  If my model changes , surely I have more things to change than just repository code, however I think it is more semantics given EF as to where the retrieve, save , update, delete code is.

Comment: @Ken the solution itself is not depended on using Entity Framework, you can change your implementation in the repository however you like, as long as it returns data based on the parameters. I did an effort to explain the difference between executing the database request in the repository and executing it in the controller (by not calling `.ToList()`). So if you call `.ToList()` in the repository, you will execute the database request in the repository.

Answer (score 16):

As Chris suggested the reason you're using ViewModel doesn't stop you from using `PagedList`.
You need to form a collection of your ViewModel objects that needs to be send to the view for paging over.

Here is a step by step guide on how you can use `PagedList` for your viewmodel data.

Your viewmodel (*I have taken a simple example for brevity and you can easily modify it to fit your needs.*)

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionName { get; set; }
}
```

and the Index method of your controller will be something like

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
     var questions = new[] {
           new QuestionViewModel { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "Question 1" },
           new QuestionViewModel { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "Question 2" },
           new QuestionViewModel { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "Question 3" },
           new QuestionViewModel { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "Question 4" }
     };

     int pageSize = 3;
     int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
     return View(questions.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

And your Index view

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ViewModel.QuestionViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc; 
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<br />

Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )
```

Here is the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924565/how-to-load-first-x-items-and-give-user-the-option-to-load-more-in-mvc-net/22925898#22925898) with my answer that has the step by step guide on how you can use `PageList`

Comment: Can you modify the example and use my ViewModel? Because the problem is that I cannot page with that ViewModel. With a simpler ViewModel it works.

Comment: @Itedone I can't really help unless you post the member properties for you `Instructors`, `Courses` and `Enrollments` classes.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to do this.  I was building an application very similar to the example/tutorial you discussed in your original question.

Here's a snippet of the code that worked for me:

```
        int pageSize = 4;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        //Used the following two formulas so that it doesn't round down on the returned integer
        decimal totalPages = ((decimal)(viewModel.Teachers.Count() /(decimal) pageSize));     
        ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling(totalPages);  
        //These next two functions could maybe be reduced to one function....would require some testing and building
        viewModel.Teachers = viewModel.Teachers.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
        ViewBag.OnePageofTeachers = viewModel.Teachers;
        ViewBag.PageNumber = pageNumber;

        return View(viewModel);
```

I added

```
using.PagedList;
```

to my controller as the tutorial states.

Now in my view my using statements etc at the top, NOTE i didnt change my using model statement.

```
@model CSHM.ViewModels.TeacherIndexData
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and then at the bottom to build my paged list I used the following and it seems to work.  I haven't yet built in the functionality for current sort, showing related data, filters, etc but i dont think it will be that difficult.

```
Page @ViewBag.PageNumber of @ViewBag.TotalPages

@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageofTeachers, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Hope that works for you.  Let me know if it works!!

Comment: I should add, I found this link really helpful:  https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

Comment: Most helpful comment, thanks man i got stuck at adding these headers u wrote there :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're using a view model has no bearing. The standard way of using `PagedList` is to store "one page of items" as a `ViewBag` variable. All you have to determine is what collection constitutes what you'll be paging over. You can't logically page multiple collections at the same time, so assuming you chose `Instructors`:

```
ViewBag.OnePageOfItems = myViewModelInstance.Instructors.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
```

Then, the rest of the standard code works as it always has.

Comment: I would join the tables inside the ViewModel and display the result in a View using a PagedList

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I have three tables mapped with the Entity Framework: Instructors, Courses and Enrollments. I need to display some fields from Instructors and some fields from Courses and display the result in a View using a PagedList