# MVC Entity Framework server side pagination PageList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

for server side pagination i am using PageList. I saw: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5omEuuIIFcg

I am using ViewModel. I followed steps given by "Dennis R".

[Using a PagedList with a ViewModel ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125329/using-a-pagedlist-with-a-viewmodel-asp-net-mvc)

But i have different kind of view model:

My Entity Class

```
public class Summary
{

}
```

viewmodel is:

```
 public class SummaryViewModel
    {
     ...         
     ....
    }

 public class DashboardViewModel
    {
       public List<SummaryViewModel> SummaryRestricted { get; set; }

       public List<SummaryViewModel> SummaryUnrestricted { get; set; }

    }
```

my Controller class:

```
public ActionResult Display(int page = 1, int pagesize = 4)
        {            
            var entitySummaries = _dbContext.Summaries.ToList();
            var vm = MapEntityToViewModel(entitySummaries );
            //return View(vm);
//return View(vm.FundsUnrestricted.ToPagedList(page, pagesize)); ????

        }

        DashboardViewModel MapEntityToViewModel(List<Summary> funds)
        {
            DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel = new DashboardViewModel();

            List<Summary> unRestricted =  funds.Where(x => xxx).ToList() ;

            List<Summary> restricted = funds.Where(x => xx).ToList();

            dashboardViewModel.SummaryUnrestricted = unRestricted.Select(x => new SummaryViewModel(x)).ToList(); 

            dashboardViewModel.SummaryRestricted = restricted.Select(x => new SummaryViewModel(x)).ToList();

            return dashboardViewModel;           
        }
```

my view is:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ViewModels.DashboardViewModel> 
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

<table id="Restricted" class="table table-bordered">
   @foreach (ViewModels.SummaryViewModel item in Model.SummaryRestricted)
    {
       <tr> <tr>
    }
</table>

<table id="UnRestricted" class="table table-bordered">
   @foreach (ViewModels.SummaryViewModel item in Model.SummaryUnrestricted )
    {
       <tr> <tr>
    }

</table>
```

my view has to display both the tables for restricted summaries and unrestricted summary on same page. can anyone help me how can i apply paging on both the tables using pageList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that. in place of list<> in view model i replace it with..

```
public class DashboardViewModel
    {
       public PagedList<SummaryViewModel> SummaryRestricted { get; set; }

       public PagedList<SummaryViewModel> SummaryUnrestricted { get; set; }

    }
```

it's working fine now.