# This is the Error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`1[abcd.Models.xyz]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

### //The Controler looks like this :-

```
namespace BusRentalSystem.Controllers
{
    public class LocationsController : Controller
    {
        private RentalData db = new RentalData();
        // GET: Locations

        public ActionResult Display(string SearchBy, string search, int? page, string sortBy)
        {
            ViewBag.ArDescription = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Ar Desc" : "";
            ViewBag.FrDescription = sortBy == "FrDescription" ? "Fr Desc" : "FrDescription";
            var locations = db.Locations.AsQueryable();  /// to be able to query from this variable
            if (SearchBy == "FrDescription")
            {

                locations = locations.Where(x => x.FrDescription.Contains(search) || search == null);

            }
            else
            {
                locations = locations.Where(x => x.ArDescription.Contains(search) || search == null);
            }

            switch (sortBy)
            {
                case "Ar Desc":
                    locations = locations.OrderByDescending(s => s.ArDescription);
                    break;
                case "Fr Desc":
                    locations = locations.OrderByDescending(s => s.FrDescription);
                    break;
                case "FrDescription":
                    locations = locations.OrderBy(s => s.FrDescription);
                    break;
                default:
                    locations = locations.OrderBy(s => s.ArDescription);
                    break;
            }

            return View("Display", locations.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 1));
        }
}
```

---

// The View looks like this:-

```
@foreach (var Locations in Model)
{

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => Locations.ArDescription)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => Locations.FrDescription)

    </td>


        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Locations.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = Locations.Id }) |
            @{
                <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">
                    <a href="/Locations?Delete=@Locations.Id" class="delLink" style="color:red;">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Locations.Id })
                    </a>
                </span>

            }
        </td>
                }
```

---

Here is the Full error message :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'PagedList.PagedList'1[BusRentalSystem.Models.Location]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'PagedList.IPagedList'1[BusRentalSystem.Models.Locations]'.

Comment: Why tag with random languages?

Comment: I don't know much about ASP, but in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125329/using-a-pagedlist-with-a-viewmodel-asp-net-mvc) they also use a paged list. Maybe you can spot obvious differences between the your code and theirs, like the missing `@model` tag in the view...

Comment: The message is self explanatory. You passing a collection of `Location` to a view which expects a collection of `Locations` (they are not the same type). Show the relevant code.

Comment: This is how Location is defined : namespace BusRentalSystem.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Location
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ArDescription { get; set; }
        public string FrDescription { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Edit your question! And you need to show the declaration of `@model ???` you use in the view

Comment: public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<BusRentalSystem.Models.Location> Locations { get; set; }     .... this is where Locations appeared

Comment: What is it you do not understand about _Edit your question_ (and again typeof `Location` is not the same as typeof `Locations`)

Answer (score 0):

Your model is excepting

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<BusRentalSystem.Models.Location>
```

Changing your view code to say this instead should fix it:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<BusRentalSystem.Models.Location>
```