# How to Display IList<T> with Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a list of error that I need to display with paging at the browser, however, I'm not pulling data from the database, I'm building this model based on a number of business logic and this list could be up to 1000 items or more. All items need to be available at the front end, that many items scrolling is cumbersome for users, that's why I need paging mechanism here.

Note: I'm using asp.net MVC framework

And, here's my error model

```
public class ErrorViewModel
{
    public string ErrorType { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList

Comment: What type of control are you binding to? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125329/using-a-pagedlist-with-a-viewmodel-asp-net-mvc) may be of help.

Comment: @Poosh plain html <div></div>

Comment: @Spectarion PagedList does a server roundtrip on every page number click and displays new items on the page, but I need to display everything on the page with paging, I cannot get them from the server as they are not saved anywhere. perhaps, you can suggest me a good js library...

Comment: DataTable is perfect for what you need.

Comment: @Spectarion would you able to give an example, please? How to achieve this via DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin which provides **client-side** search and paging (server delivers all the data to the client, not recommended but this is what you asked for).

First, download the DataTables plugin and include it in your project and layout file.

Second, you need to render HTML table using Razor syntax.

```
@model IEnumerable<ErrorViewModel>

<table class="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Error type</th>
            <th>Error message</th>
            <th>Additional message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Model.ErrorType</td>
                <td>@Model.ErrorMessage</td>
                <td>@Model.AdditionalMessage</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Third, add this code at the end of your layout file (**after you import jQuery and DataTables plugin.**).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.data-table').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Example here: **[jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/pejojiqape/edit?html,output)**

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Spectarion, you can use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin. Since you're using ASP.net MVC, I suggest using [DataTables.ASPNet](https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.aspnet) which provides a nice server-side support and helpers for jQuery DataTables. It is easy to use, just follow the documentation and download the sample project.