# How to limit the paging size in Grid.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I am new to grid.mvc.I want to show only starting 2-3 grid pages and the last page.like [with page sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBwfd.png)

but its coming like this

[without page sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS3cN.png)

my code is-

```
public ActionResult VendorOrderListPartial()
        {
            var model = VendorManager.GetAllVendorOrders();
            ViewBag.paging = GlobalSettingsInfo.GridPageSize;
            var grid = this.gridMvcHelper.GetAjaxGrid(model.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderId));

            return View("VendorOrderListPartial", grid);

        }

    @Html.Grid(Model).Named("VendorOrderListPartial").Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Add(c => c.OrderNo).Titled("Ord#").Filterable(true);

        columns.Add(c => c.OrderDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Titled("Order Date").Filterable(true);

        columns.Add(c => c.ProdStatus).Titled("Prod.Status").Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(c => c.OrderAmount).Titled("Total Amount").Filterable(true);

        columns.Add().Titled("View").Filterable(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("View", "VendorOrderDetailView", "WebVendor", new { id = o.OrderId }, null)).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false);

    }).WithPaging(@ViewBag.paging).Sortable(true)
```

any help will be appreciated..Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa

Comment: Did you check the code/Html-differences between the example and your project?

Comment: @Nikolaus Yes i have..can u share some working examples of this

Comment: @SHK No but can you show the Html of your example page? I don’t have any experience with grid.MVC, but I’ll give it a try.

Comment: the cshtml is already here,below the actionresult method

Comment: You should use PagedList.Mvc.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125329/using-a-pagedlist-with-a-viewmodel-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found a solution.

I'm assuming that you are using the grid.mvc with ajax. In *_AjaxGridPager.cshtml*, check **Model.PagePartitionSize** property.

If Model.PagePartitionSize = 0, set it to 10 for instance.

**EDIT**
In your controller, after you initialize a gridMvcHelper.GetAjaxGrid object, you change the property.

Example

```
var grid = gridMvcHelper.GetAjaxGrid<question>((IOrderedQueryable<question>)QuestionsAfterSearch.OrderByDescending(x => x.idQuestion).AsQueryable(), page);
grid.AjaxGridSettings.PagePartitionSize = 10;
```