# Getting "Sequence contains no elements?" when using paged List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagination, pagedlist

Please do not mark this as a duplicate because I've already checked these but none of them helped me.

[Sequence contains no elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324199/sequence-contains-no-elements)

[Using a PagedList with a ViewModel ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125329/using-a-pagedlist-with-a-viewmodel-asp-net-mvc)

I'm trying to use pagedList in my asp.net mvc project but it's giving me "Sequence contains no elements?" when I click on page numbers.
First I have 2 Table Products and Images.

Product Contains: ProductID - ProductName - ProductDescription.

Images contains :ImageID - ImagePath - ProductFK

I have a viewModel That contains these 2 tables

```
public class myViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<Products> myProducts { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Images> myImages{ get; set; }
}
```

In my Search View I have this.

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<myViewModel>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

 <div>
 <input type="text"  name="search">
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
 </div>
 @foreach (Products item in Model.First().myProducts)
   {
    @item.ProductName
    @item.ProductDescription
    }
<div>

// Page Index

 @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount


 @Html.PagedListPager(Model.First().myProducts, page => Url.Action("Search", new { page, search = Request.QueryString["search"] }), PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
```

And Here's my search method in my home controller

```
public ActionResult Search(string search, int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var Items= new[] {
       new myViewModel { myProducts = DB.Products.Where(a=>a.ProductName.Contains(search)).OrderByDescending(a=>a.ProductID).ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize),
            }
 };

return View(Items.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

The search worked great and even the page index is giving me the number of pages depending on my search results(meaning that if I have a product with a name="abc" and I have 9 abc products in my table, if I'm showing 3 element only in each page ,Im getting 1,2,3 for page indexing.)

The only thing the goes wrong is when I click on a page number to navigate to other results, it gives me "Sequence contains no elements".
Please if someone can help me, it would be so appreciated .

Comment: What do you think `Model.First()` does if there are no elements?

Comment: Yep. Both of those things are doing exactly as expected. Have you read the docs for `First` and `FirstOrDefault`?