# Cannot resolve symbol 'ToPagedList'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with the following Tutorial on MVC 5 in C# .NET 4.5

[Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

I get a compile error "Cannot resolve symbol 'ToPagedList'"

**I am wondering if the turorial is out of date or am I missing something?**

[image: Cannot resolve symbol 'ToPagedList']

These are my using statements

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Comment: The link you shared is not working for me. But it is likely that you are missing the `PagedList` pagkage in you application as I shared in my answer below.

Comment: That link isn't working for me either right now, but I have a cached copy and you are right about NuGet, I guess this is a case of RTFM (Read the *&*$ manual) on my part, thanks Dennis

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the tutorial is using `PagedList` for pagination. You may need to install the required components for using `PagedList` in your code. Here is the link to [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/)

Through the Package Manager Console you can do

```
PM> Install-Package PagedList.Mvc
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924565/how-to-load-first-x-items-and-give-user-the-option-to-load-more-in-mvc-net/22925898#22925898) to my another post on SO detailing the step-by-step process on how you can use `PagedList` in your MVC application.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that?