# ERROR: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to type 'X.PagedList.IPagedList'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I use List  instead of IEnumerable  model

My Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        { 
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var itemCount = employees.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5);
            return View(employees.ToList());
        }
```

My View

```
@Html.Partial("EmployeeList", Model.AsEnumerable())

@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.AsEnumerable(), page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel>` can't be directly cast to `IPagedList` with `(IPagedList)Model.AsEnumerable()` since they're different instances. You should return a `PagedList` instance using `ToPagedList` method as `View` argument (assumed `employees` is an `List<EmployeeViewModel>` or array of viewmodels):

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{ 
    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    return View(employees.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5));
}
```

And use the bound model inside `PagedListPager` like this:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<EmployeeViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc; 

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

And pass the `IPagedList` through `Model` in `HtmlHelper.Partial`:

```
@Html.Partial("EmployeeList", Model)
```

Similar issue:

[How to load first x items and give user the option to load more in MVC.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924565/how-to-load-first-x-items-and-give-user-the-option-to-load-more-in-mvc-net/22925898#22925898)

Comment: Thanks after fixing it it shows 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'X.PagedList.PagedList' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: Can you show your `@model` directive in partial view & view code? Seems you're still using `IEnumerable` for `@model` directive as in this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ. Change it to use `PagedList` properly.

Comment: this one?
    @Html.Partial("EmployeeList", Model)

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))

Comment: Yes, `Model.AsEnumerable()` should be just `Model` since you want to bind `PagedList` (the former will return `IEnumerable<PagedList>`).

Comment: even if I change that to Model it still shows  ERROR: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'X.PagedList.PagedList`1[App.Models.EmployeeViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App.Models.EmployeeViewModel]'. what codes do you need to verify where my mistake is? thank you for your patience and help

Comment: public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public EmployeeViewModel() { }
        public EmployeeViewModel(Employee model)
        {
              //getter setter
        }
              //getter setter
    }

Comment: I think you're using different viewmodels for main page & partial page, try to use base viewmodel to hold both `IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel>` and `PagedList` described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view.

Comment: ahh yes, I keep on editing the wrong view instead of using the partial view, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

### **Controller Action **

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        { 
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;            
            return View(employees.ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5));
        }
```

### **View page**

```
    @using PagedList
    @using PagedList.Mvc
    @model IEnumerable <Employee>

    @Html.Partial("EmployeeList", Model)

    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```